# How to use shared object file in c compilation

Tags: c, gcc, shared-libraries

I'm trying to use [this](https://github.com/dlbeer/quirc) C library using `gcc Apple LLVM version 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.42.1)` on macOS Sierra. I've done the following steps:

1. `make libquirc.so`
2. Copied `libquirc.so` into my project directory
3. `gcc -o quirc_test quirc_test.c -L. -l libquirc.so.1.0`

It produces the error:

```
quirc_test.c:1:10: fatal error: 'quirc.h' file not found
#include <quirc.h>
         ^
1 error generated.
```

**quirc_test.c**

```
#include <quirc.h>
```

This is the first time I've tried to do anything in C and other related questions about compiling with the `link` flag didn't seem to help as seen above.

Comment: Where is the file it is saying is missing?

Comment: @ChrisTurner it's in the repo. I thought the compiled `.so` file contains all the information needed?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: After 5 years here, you should know [ask]!

Answer (score 2):

C is somewhat primitive. Shared object libraries do not contain the declaration of the API they implement - at least not in enough detail or a form that the compiler can understand.

You'll need the header file `quirc.h` somewhere you can find it. You could just copy it into the current directory just like the library, but you'll need a minor adjustment to the include statement.

```
#include "quirc.h"
```

If the included file is surrounded by double quotes instead of angle brackets, it will first look in the source code directory instead of the system header directories.

An alternative is to install the library somewhere e.g. /usr/local. Your library would go in /usr/local/lib nd your header in /usr/local/include. If you do that, use the `-I` directive on the compiler command line to tell the compiler where to look for the header e.g.

```
cc -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib -lquirc  quirc_test.c
```

Comment: I noticed that the repo contains a [/lib](https://github.com/dlbeer/quirc/tree/master/lib) directory which contains other object files and headers, including `quirc.h`. Does it make sense to copy this entire thing over to my project folder? In that case, do I need the -I flag ?

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot `make install` because the library installs some demos of its usage which rely on linux dependencies unavailable on macOS.

Comment: You can manually install the library and headers simply by copying them into the right place and settign permissions and ownership (you'll need sudo). If you choose to keep the lib in your own directory, you'll find the exe won't run if you move it anywhere else.